# Не запускается веб приложение через режим отладки IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee, jboss

Через `Run` все работает, а если попробовать через `Debug`, то выдает ошибку:

`Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:8085`

Адрес: `localhost:8085`, сервер: `JBoss 4.2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отладки нужно настроить в `Run/Debug conf` во вкладке `Remote` новую конфигурацию. Там указать хост: то что вы указали в настройках запуска; порт: при старте `JBoss` в самом начале есть строчка: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 18787`, в ней `18787` и есть наш порт; указать отлаживаемый модуль.